# React TypeScript onSubmit e.preventDefault() not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, typescript, form-submit

I'm building a simple user search app using React and TypeScript. I have a basic form with an input text box to search users and an input button that submits the search. But the `e.preventDefault()` method in my `onSubmit` method doesn't seem to be working. When I submit, the whole app refreshes. Actually, it may be that `onSubmit` isn't even being called at all.

```js
  private handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({text: ''});
  }

  private handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({text: e.currentTarget.value});
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form">
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="text" 
            value={this.state.text} 
            placeholder="Search Users..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input 
            type="submit"
            value="search"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-block" 
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This should help you out: https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/react-event-preventdefault-78c28c950e46

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are adding `onSubmit`in the wrong place.

You should add in the `form` not in the button.

```
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>                    // \/ added here
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="text" 
            value={this.state.text} 
            placeholder="Search Users..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input                 // removed from the button
            type="submit"
            value="search"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-block" 
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

If you look at [the example on the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) you will see that they add it in the `form`.

*Remember that to trigger the `form`'s `onSubmit`, your `input`/`button` needs to have `type="submit"`

Answer (score 13):

You can simply do this :-

```
 private handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({text: ''});
  }

  private handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({text: e.currentTarget.value});
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form"   onSubmit={(e) =>this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="text" 
            value={this.state.text} 
            placeholder="Search Users..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input 
            type="submit"
            value="search"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-block" 
          
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Also in addition to moving the event from onClick to onSubmit, to get the event from the form, type React.FormEvent works.

````
  private handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({text: ''});
  }```

Instead of e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>
````

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the similar issue by removing `e.preventDefault` from handleSubmit function and adding `**onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); this.handleSubmit()}}**` on button.
and you have to put onSubmit on Form.

```
  private handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({text: ''});
  }
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="text" 
            value={this.state.text} 
            placeholder="Search Users..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input 
            type="submit"
            value="search"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-block" 
            onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); this.handleSubmit()}}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is tested and should work.

Comment: The form submit handler should have an event type of: e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

return (
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder='John Doe'/>

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder='example@doamin.com'/>

            <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
)
```